# Generating a sha256 from bash (without echo)

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a basic script that runs through a file line by line, encrypts each line with sha256 and then compares it against a fixed test for matching results.

`file.txt`

```
foo
bar
bazz
password
```

my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="./file.txt"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do
    password="5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8"
    echo "Testing $line: "
    try=$line | sha256sum
    if [[ "$try" == "$password" ]] ; then
        echo "match"
    else
        echo "no match"
    fi
done <"$file"
```

result:

```
testing foo
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  -
no match
testing bar
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  -
no match
testing bazz
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  -
no match
testing password
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  -
no match
```

I believe the `try=$line | sha256sum` to be the issue here because if I run it by itself using an example from the `file.txt`:

```
foo | sha256sum
foo: command not found
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  -
```

Placing `foo` in "" doesn't alter the result above

The only way I was able to get it to correctly handle the pipe was to place a `echo` in front:

```
echo -n foo | sha256sum
2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae
```

This isn't the desired results as I don't want to print each sha256sum I just want to encode the line and then check it. If it matches then print match, else no match.

Expected results:

```
testing foo #2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae  -
no match
testing bar #fcde2b2edba56bf408601fb721fe9b5c338d10ee429ea04fae5511b68fbf8fb9  -
no match
testing bazz #ef9b462f01f881c97791114d6244476bb33e418d3dbe0ee0967c4c80e764cd9c  -
no match
testing password #5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8  -
match
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

printing the line in order to pipe it to `sha256` won't print it to the screen.  However, if you want to capture the output of `sha256` you'll want to use a command substitution instead of just running the command.

That line should be:

```
try="$(printf '%s' "$line" | sha256sum | cut -f1 -d' ')"
```

We'll use [`printf` instead of `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) and then we capture `stdout` from the pipeline and store that in our variable `try`.  Also, `sha256sum` prints the file from which it was reading, including `stdin`, so we'll use `cut` to get rid of that part.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation included with the solution! Really helps new people out ! :D